# "Sometime" vs "some of the time"

Tags: difference

I see the expression "some of the time" being used quite often. For instance;

"You can fool all the people some of the time, and some of the people all the time, but you cannot fool all the people all the time." - Abraham Lincoln

I wonder if "some of the time" is exactly the same as "sometime" or is there any difference between the two?

Regards,

Comment: I think _sometimes_ would be a better substitute than _sometime_, particularly in contexts like the one you quote.

Answer (score 2):

"Sometime" means that **something will occur at an unspecified time**, such as "he'll meet us sometime soon" - there is no direct statement of when exactly he'll arrive.

**"...of the time" refers to probability,** and it means that something would occur or happen with `X` reliability. In this case, you're using the determiner "some", which **can mean about a 50/50 chance**. For example, if I were to say that "the clock goes off some of the time," I would mean that the clock does not always go off. It does occasionally, but not always.

You might also be confusing "sometime" with "sometimes"; there is in fact a difference, like J.R.♦ pointed out. **"Sometimes" means virtually the same thing as "some of the time"** - in fact, it is literally a contraction of it. This is probably what you were looking for.